# Release only one module in multimodule maven project

Tags: module, maven, hudson, maven-release-plugin

I have one Multimodule maven projects which has nearly 20 modules. there is one common module which changes rarely and other 19 are independent of each other.
Issue is when I change one module and go for release with hudson, It releases all modules.

If I go to specify version number for each module, it is very tedious job to change all numbers.

It is like increase in version number unneccessarily and also wastage of time/memory.
For e.g. if I change each out of 19 twice , the common version will go to 1.39 or 39.0 which I don't want to avoid confusion. we are using standard release plugin.

Is there any way to manage release such that we can release only one module instead of whole project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just go into your module's directory:

```
cd module19
mvn deploy
```

To release with hudson, just make a job for each submodule (*module1* through *module19*) and a job for the *common module* and the *parent pom* (use `mvn -N` to deploy the parent pom).